# Can part of Text node be highlighted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating [Text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) like `var liContent = document.createTextNode(someHtmlString);`.
And then add this variable into list like `$("<li/>").html(liContent).appendTo(targetUnorderList);`

**Question is:** Can I highlight some text in the `liContent` item?
And if "Yes" - how can I do that?
*Clarification:* I need to highlight partial content within `li`. For example, word `Nice`.

**Update:**
At the same time I need to display all content of Text node just like a text (including `html` tags).

**Update 2:** No processing is allowed on the string which need to be displayed. Seems there are no solution, because Text node is interpreted by browser just like a plain text.

Whole code example (working):

```js
var someHtmlString = "<i class='icon-window-add'>Nice text here</i>";
var targetUnorderList = $("#targetUnorderList");
var liContent = document.createTextNode(someHtmlString);
$("<li/>").html(liContent).appendTo(targetUnorderList)[0];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="targetUnorderList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What you mean by _highlight_ ?

Comment: Some color or any other way to highlight the word in that node.

Comment: if you want to highlight the entire content of `li`, then add a css class selector targetting `li`, if its partial content within `li`, then you need to enclose that partial text, within `span` and then target the span from css selector to apply a specific color

Comment: If you are using jquery then why are you using `document.createTextNode`?

Comment: @anu because I am not sure what is jQuery related action. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

try this , it will show the "highlighted text" in red color

```js
var someHtmlString1 = "<i class='icon-window-add'>Nice ";
var someHtmlString2="Highlighted text</span>";
var someHtmlString3="here</i>";
var targetUnorderList = $("#targetUnorderList");
var span1Text=document.createTextNode(someHtmlString1);
var span3Text=document.createTextNode(someHtmlString3);
var li=$("<li/>");
var span1=$("<span/>").html(span1Text).appendTo(li);
var span2=$("<span style='color:red'/>").html(someHtmlString2).appendTo(span1);
var span3=$("<span/>").html(span3Text).appendTo(li);

   

   li.appendTo(targetUnorderList)[0];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="targetUnorderList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm... this is little bit closer to what I want. But I need to check with my whole solution to define if this is a good solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could just create a custom class `highlight` then wrap the text you want to highlight by span with this class, Since you're using jQuery it could be done simply like :

```
$("<li/>").html("<i class='icon-window-add'>Nice <span class='highlight'>text here</span></i>");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var li = $("<li/>").html("&lt;i class='icon-window-add'&gt;Nice <span class='highlight'>text here</span>&lt;/i&gt;");

$("#targetUnorderList").append(li);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="targetUnorderList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So, You escaped `<` and `>` and your input for `.html()` is no more valid html. My problem is that I get valid html and need to display it on page with highlighting some words.